# Rendering multi character emoji in SkiaSharp

Tags: xamarin, unicode, emoji, skiasharp, skia

I am rendering emoji in SkiaSharp and have been able to get it to work correctly for simple emoji (like  or ) but not more complex emoji (like  or ‍).

The trickiest part was setting the correct typeface containing the emoji since there is no support for fallback fonts as noted here: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/232

Here is a simplified version of the code I am using:

```
int GrinningFaceEmoji = 0x1f600;

void DrawEmoji(SKCanvas canvas, string emoji, int x, int y) {

    SKPaint paint = new SKPaint();
    paint.Typeface = SKFontManager.CreateDefault().MatchCharacter(GrinningFaceEmoji);

    canvas.DrawText(emoji, x, y, vtsm.paint);
}
```

When `emoji` is a simple emoji, it works perfectly, but more complex emoji show up as multiple-characters. The light baby shows as two characters - the yellow baby followed by a color square. The artist shows as three characters. I am currently testing this on macOS.

Comment: Canvas DrawText is almost unusable directly in real world. If you want to localize app to other languages, like arabic o hebrew, you have to use text shaping. Try to SkiaSharp HarfBuzz and use extension DrawShapedText if it helps.

Comment: Hi Michal. Yes, have done a lot of work to make DrawText work, switching fonts as needed, etcetera.

Are you using [SkiaSharp.Harfbuzz](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.harfbuzz)? I couldn't find a way to measure text in this API. Also, do you know if DrawShapedText would actually render the emoji correctly? Finally, do you have any idea of the performance overhead imposed by DrawShapedText vs DrawText?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SkiaSharp.HarfBuzz. I had my app ready when we sent demo to our Israeli partner and everything was broken. Then I realized, that there is probably no place in the app where I can draw text without Harfbuzz. It took me some time to implement text drawing correctly - RTL, LTR & combinations, including numbers etc. Harfbuzz solves only text shaping - super important in some languages, if text start with LTR whole text is treated like LTR - you must split it to segments and position them. Neither harfbuzz help with font fallback.

Comment: To your questions, performance of text rendering is not an issue in my app and I do a lot of things to draw text (see above) . Font fallback must be implemented manually :( - I used shortcut and compiled my own font which includes all requested characters. I don't know if your emoji will work, but if it is from one font file, it could.

Comment: I just found this [SO about emoji and HarfBuzz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720755/emoji-modifiers-zwj-sequences-using-harfbuzz-freetype-in-apple-color-emoji), which seems to indicate that HarfBuzz will indeed render the characters correctly. I'll give it a try...

Comment: I've gone through the pain of font fallback already. RTL I may just put off for the moment. Thanks for sharing your experience Michal.

Comment: FYI, tried SkiaSharp.HarfBuzz 1.68.0 on macOS and it does not render multi character emoji properly either. Output from DrawShapedText is the same as the standard DrawText.

Comment: Then you probably need fallback and emoji font.

Comment: Update: As of SkiaSharp 2.80.2, HarfBuzz on Windows and macOS does render emoji with skin tone modifiers correctly (). It still doesn't render ‍ correctly unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

In order to render complex text like colored emojis or some shaped text like arabic you would just use

**`SKCanvas.DrawShapedText`**

instead of `SKCanvas.DrawText`.
This extension method resides inside `SkiaSharp.HarfBuzz.CanvasExtensions` static class.

Comment: This does not work for complex emoji. Even as of today, SkiaSharpHarfBuzz 2.88.7, the painter ‍ does not render properly.

Comment: Provide proof or didn't happen.

Comment: As per comments, the painter has not been rendering correctly since 2019. In 2021 the skin tone modifiers started working but painter did not. This remains the case now. Try it yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: It's working fine, i am using DrawShapedText: https://github.com/taublast/AppoMobi.Maui.DrawnUi.Demo

Comment: Direct link to working code https://github.com/taublast/DrawnUi.Maui/blob/4840f338fcc29748e25b5aac4a13bdd7b46fe5ef/src/Engine/Draw/Text/SkiaLabel.cs#L1089